# Gradle deploy project to ear

Tags: java, web-applications, gradle, weblogic, ear

I have project with below structure

```
--MyPrj.ear
  --APP-INF
    --src
    --lib
  --META-INF
    --application.xml
    --weblogic-application.xml
  --WEB_MAIN
    --assets
    --WEB-INF
      --conf
      --web.xml
      --weblogic.xml
```

I want to deploy to PRJ.ear file with below structure:

```
--MyPrj.ear
  --APP-INF
    --classes
    --lib
  --META-INF
    --application.xml
    --weblogic-application.xml
  --WEB_MAIN
    --assets
    --WEB-INF
      --conf
      --web.xml
      --weblogic.xml
```

And here is my ear configuration:

```
ear {
    baseName 'PRJ'
    appDirName 'APP-INF/src'
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'

    ear{
        into("META-INF"){
            from("META-INF") {
                exclude 'application.xml'
            }
        }
        into("WEB_MAIN") {
            from ("WEB_MAIN")
        }
    }

    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule 'WEB_MAIN', '/'
        applicationName = "PRJ"
    }
}
```

My actual result:

```
--MyPrj.ear
  --APP-INF
    --lib
  --com
  --META-INF
    --application.xml
    --weblogic-application.xml
  --WEB_MAIN
    --assets
    --WEB-INF
      --conf
      --web.xml
      --weblogic.xml
```

Cannot generate `APP-INF/classes`

Comment: What issue are you running into?

Comment: I see, you've already modified your `buid.gradle` , so is the problem only in doing deploy process or some other thing is wrong with your build file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with an observation: Both instances of `ear` in your build script refer to the same task. There is no need to refer to `ear` twice, i.e. the `into` declarations can go one level up.

First, add the folder `APP-INF/src` as a source set. This will result in the compiled classes being added to the root of the EAR, so you have to exclude these. Then you have to tell the `ear` task to copy the compiled classes to the `APP-INF/classes` directory in the EAR:

```
// Make sure the source files are compiled.
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'APP-INF/src'
        }
    }
}

ear {
    baseName 'PRJ'
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'

    into("META-INF") {
        from("META-INF") {
            exclude 'application.xml'
        }
    }
    into("WEB_MAIN") {
        from("WEB_MAIN")
    }

    deploymentDescriptor {
        webModule 'WEB_MAIN', '/'
        applicationName = "PRJ"
    }

    // Exclude the compiled classes from the root of the EAR.
    // Replace "com/javathinker/so/" with your package name.
    eachFile { copyDetails ->
        if (copyDetails.path.startsWith('com/javathinker/so/')) {
            copyDetails.exclude()
        }
    }

    // Copy the compiled classes to the desired directory.
    into('APP-INF/classes') {
        from(compileJava.outputs)
    }

    // Remove empty directories to keep the EAR clean.
    includeEmptyDirs false
}
```

Comment: It's great. I will check it. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

To include `.ear` file you should modify `build.gradle` by adding `apply plugin: 'ear'` to it and filling the `ear` block correctly by following the instructions in [this guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html).

Also, the magic of deployment process is quite well explained [here](http://themrsion.blogspot.ru/2013/11/gradle-weblogic-deployment-using.html), shortly it's about using `wideploy` tool in Gradle.
You may also want to take a look [here](https://github.com/willis7/weblogic-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/weblogic/WLDeploy.groovy) to find some more detailed info about this script.

Comment: could you check this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978589/gradle-custom-ear

Comment: I want to custom .ear structure

Comment: what do you mean by saying that you can't deploy your .ear, any particular errors or something?

Comment: There is no error but the result is not what I wan't. Can you check this link for more detail? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-ear-plugin-compile-source-to-specified-output-folder/11162

Comment: wild guess, but are you sure your `appDirName ` is correct? The default behavior of the Ear task is to copy the content of application source directory to the root of the archive, which (I suppose) is your goal, and since `APP-INF/classes` is lost somewhere, maybe gradle didn't find a correct way to classes .

Comment: No. It's not. I want to create *APP-INF/classes* in .ear file. But I don't know how to

Comment: And what happens if you define `appDirName` as it recommends in official guide (default value for this property is `src/main/application`, but yours may differ according to project structure). If you haven't tried this, try now, or post the result here.

Comment: I suppose you've tried `gradlew clean` and rebuild several times already?