# Gradle custom ear

Tags: java, web-applications, gradle, weblogic, ear

I would like to deploy my project with below structure:

```
--MyPrj.ear
  --APP-INF
    --classes
    --lib
  --META-INF
    --application.xml
    --weblogic-application.xml
  --WEB_MAIN
    --assets
    --WEB-INF
      --conf
      --web.xml
      --weblogic.xml
```

And here is my ear configuration

```
ear {
    appDirName 'APP-INF/src'
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'

    deploymentDescriptor {
        applicationName = "MyPRJ"
        displayName = "My Project"
        description = "My Project"
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? what doesn't work? what errors have you got?

Comment: @MarkFisher: Actually, I can't deploy the ear file with my expected structure